# Incorporating closed-source derivative into GPL code

Tags: gpl-3, closed-source

I have a closed-source project. I am the copyright holder.

Can I incorporate parts from my closed-source project into an open-source project without running into legal issues commercially using my closed-source project?

Please note that the part incorporated into the open-source project would be a derivative of a small part of the closed-source project.

Answer (score 6):

If you are the sole author of the entire closed-source project, then nothing prevents you from extracting a part of the project and releasing that under another license, either as a new standalone project or incorporated into another project.  This would have no effect on the licensing status of your closed-source project.

Standard IANAL/TINLA disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.